# Moq Framework Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Tags: entity-framework, moq

I'm having trouble with setting up my Moq Framework when it comes to simple tests for updating entities, I'm attempting to Moq my entityframework and it works fine for all tests except for ones which involve editing data. 
The error i receive is Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. I've looked into it as much as i can and all the suggestions are to include

```
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

or to add

.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

on my foreign keys, which i already have done for creating the database in the first place. I feel that Moq seems to just be ignoring these.
Does anyone have experience on this and if so any suggestions?

Thanks

Edit

Working Test

```
    [Test]
    public void TestInsert()
    {
        //Assign
        testCustomer = new Customer() { CustomerID = 2, CustomerName = "Test Customer", Active = true };

        mockContext = new Mock<efContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.Set<Customer>())
            .Returns(new FakeCustomerDbSet
            {
                testCustomer
            });

        mockUnitOfWork = DataAccess.GetMockUnitOfWork(mockContext.Object);
        ManageCustomer sut = new ManageCustomer(ref mockUnitOfWork);
        Customer testCustomer = new Customer() { CustomerName = "Test Customer2", Active = true };

        //Act
        sut.Insert(testCustomer);
        Customer testCustomer2 = sut.GetBy(x => x.CustomerName == "Test Customer2").SingleOrDefault();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(testCustomer, testCustomer2);
    }
```

Testing Method

```
    public virtual T Insert(T entity)
    {
        dynamic dyn = entity;
        dyn.Active = true;

        entity = Repo.Insert((T)dyn);
        Repo.Commit();

        return entity;
    }
```

Failed Test

```
    public void TestDeleteByEntity()
    {
        //Assign
        TestIntializer();
        ManageCustomer sut = new ManageCustomer(ref mockUnitOfWork);

        //Act
        sut.Delete(testCustomer);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNull(sut.GetBy(x => x.CustomerID == testCustomer.CustomerID).SingleOrDefault());
    }
```

Test Method

```
    public virtual bool Delete(T entity)
    {
        dynamic DynamicEntity = entity;
        DynamicEntity.Active = false;

        return Update(DynamicEntity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entityToUpdate)
    {
        var attached = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(x => x == entityToUpdate).FirstOrDefault();

        if (attached != null)
        {
            attached.CurrentValues.SetValues(entityToUpdate);
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the entity's state to modified
            _context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a test and the code it is testing?

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: what type is ``mockUnitOfWork`` ?

Comment: It is my repository basically, I'm passing in the mock efcontext into that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the details of the `Update` method, here, so I'll have to do some guesswork, but here's what it looks like:

It seems to me the `Update` method is making some method calls to your `mockUnitOfWork` field and it seems it is not of type `Mock<T>`

You should pass a Mock object instead of a concrete implementation.

It seems the concrete implementation is getting you the error you mentionned. By using a mocked version of the unit

Try only keeping the `sut` as a concrete implementation within your tests. Any other code outside of your `sut` will make your test less **unit**ary.

The implementation of your `UnitOfWork.Delete()`, on the other hand, will be tested in another dedicated test.

There is a point, though, where you will have to test a class that issues a SQL command. At that point, you will probably want to keep that class as thin as possible, and test it, not with **unit** tests, but with **integration** test.

Why? Simply because if you test that your SQL command gets you the desired result, you are not unit-testing your unit-of-work : You are testing the integration between said unit-of-work, and the SQL database.

Comment: The issue with making the mockUnitOfWork an actual mock object is when i pass it into the sut such as ManageCustomer sut = new ManageCustomer(ref mockUnitOfWork);, the code will complain saying can not convert type mock<t> into t. Which is why I've had to leave it as that.

Comment: You need to have an interface (or at the very least, virtual members, but honestly, stick to interfaces) as your T. This is basically how moq works, by design.

Comment: Looking at your implementation of Update, the field _context, inside your sut will also need to be mocked as a Mock<T>.

Comment: At some point, however, you will get too close to the metal to be able to unit test a DB access. As I said in my answer, keep the class that accesses the DB as thin as possible.

Comment: the         mockContext = new Mock<efContext>(); is the _context. It gets passed to the repository by the         mockUnitOfWork = DataAccess.GetMockUnitOfWork(mockContext.Object);.  Could it be that I'm passing in the mockContext.Object rather than the mockContext itself

Comment: As mentionned: keep your mocks based on interfaces. If no interface is available on yout context: Wrap it !

Comment: Also, is GetMockUnitOfWork a static method, or an instance method ?

Comment: It's a Static Method

Comment: You can't mock a static method with moq. You need to open inject an instance of a service and call an instance method to be able to mock it and setup the return value in order to have control over it and return yet again a mock object. Otherwise it will try to perform actual calls to your db and it will fail, showing the error message you mentioned.

Comment: Did my answer + comments help?

Comment: I'm not attempting to mock the static method, I'm just passing in a mocked object into the static method   IUnitOfWork mockUnitOfWork = DataAccess.GetMockUnitOfWork(mockContext.Object);. with the mock object being my mocked entityFramework

Comment: You've been helpful in that I'm understanding the problem a bit more but still haven't figured out the fix yet

Comment: Okay, I'll try to summarize. Basically, your problem is the following : your sut is making calls to the DB. you should never call the DB from your SUT. In order to avoid it, wrap your DB calls behind injected dependencies. Once they are wrapped behind injected dependencies, you can mock them so that they don't actually call the DB. The problem is : at the moment, the methods that touch the DB are static methods and can't be mocked. change that! Hide them behind injected dependencies, mock their methods and you'll be out of the woods.

Comment: Also, is efContext a class or an interface ? if it is a class, this is also a problem: don't do partial mocking : only work with interfaces, otherwise, you'll have to face dealing with objects that are half-mocks, half-production code. the only production code you should execute is the one of the class of the Sut.